# App ID Name And Bundle Identifier Issue

Tags: ios, bundle-identifier

In iOS Dev Center, under identifiers and App IDs, i have created the id:

```
com.thisisanapp.thisisanapp
```

while the name is "ThisIsAnApp"

I want the id to be following with capital first letters:

```
com.thisisanapp.ThisIsAnApp
```

Since there is no delete button, i tried creating another one with capital first letters but it says the id with this bundle identifier is not available. It is taking the name with capital letters and without capital letters the same. How can i fix it???

I just want to have an identifier as com.thisisanapp.ThisIsAnApp.

Comment: If you're looking to change how your app name is displayed you can do that by changing the Bundle display name, as far as actually changing the identifier, I'm not sure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

EDIT:
There is now a delete button for App IDs again and it works.

There used to be a 'Delete' button for App IDs on the website, but it was hidden at some point in the past.  It is unknown if Apple will re-enable this button sometime in the future.

My suggestion would be to use the ID you made.  You only need to set it in the Info.plist for your app and can pretty much forget about it after that.  This ID is never user facing so it doesn't have to be pretty.  Alternatively, you could email Apple directly.  As long as you haven't put a build on sale using that ID, they should have no problem removing it for you.

Answer (score 1):

This was working in past, but doesn't work anymore.

Consider creating id "com.thisisanapp2.ThisIsAnApp". This one will still be unique.
You can also change your app name to "thisisanapp", but it's more work to do.